# Why is RegEx ignoring the second match if immediately following the first?

Tags: javascript, regex, dom-events

I have a string: `'4 0 13 0 0 30 32 0 14 9 27 0 27 20 4 0 22 0'`. The value I want my RegEx to find is contained within a variable named `targetValue`. 
In this case `targetValue` happens to equal `0` and I want all matches to be replaced with bolder text. Here is the basic code:

```js
function startReplacing(){
  var targetValue = 0;
  var replacer = ' <b> ' + targetValue + ' </b> ';
  var re = new RegExp('\\s'+targetValue+'\\s','gi');

  var str = document.getElementById('string').innerHTML;
  str = str.replace(re, replacer);

  document.getElementById('string').innerHTML = str;
}
```

```css
b{ font-size:125% }
```

```html
<p id="string"> 4 0 13 0 0 30 32 0 14 9 27 0 27 20 4 0 22 0 </p>
<button onclick="startReplacing()">REPLACE</button>
```

After clicking "REPLACE" Do you notice the *"0"* before the value *"30"*? My RegEx *missed* this value. How can I change my code to fix this?

Note: My RegEx Misses **all** values that should match immediately following a first match.

Comment: Because it cannot match the whitespace twice.

Comment: @Bergi I see. It's already matching one occurrence. Brilliant. Is there an easy fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex tries to match a space before the number and after the number. If there is only one space between two numbers, it cannot match them both.

I suspect you don't want to match the whitespaces at all, and just need to check that there's no other digit. Use a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) for that:

```js
function startReplacing(){
  var targetValue = 0;
  var replacer = ' <b> ' + targetValue + ' </b> ';
  var re = new RegExp('\\b'+targetValue+'\\b','g');
//                     ^^^               ^^^

  var str = document.getElementById('string').innerHTML;
  str = str.replace(re, replacer);

  document.getElementById('string').innerHTML = str;
}
```

```css
b{ font-size:125% }
```

```html
<p id="string">4 0 13 0 0 30 32 0 14 9 27 0 27 20 4 0 22 0</p>
<!-- works without leading and trailing spaces even -->
<button onclick="startReplacing()">REPLACE</button>
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Thank you for helping us newbies.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you match a '0', it will consume the space immediately following it therefore, it will not be available for the next '0' after it. You can solve this by using a lookahead which would match the space but does not consume it so that the next time around it is still there.

```js
function startReplacing(){
  var targetValue = 0;
  var replacer = ' <b> ' + targetValue + ' </b> ';
  var re = new RegExp('\\s'+targetValue+'(?=\\s)','gi');

  var str = document.getElementById('string').innerHTML;
  str = str.replace(re, replacer);

  document.getElementById('string').innerHTML = str;
}
```

```css
b{ font-size:125% }
```

```html
<p id="string"> 4 0 13 0 0 30 32 0 14 9 27 0 27 20 4 0 22 0 </p>
<button onclick="startReplacing()">REPLACE</button>
```

Comment: Had no idea about those. Thanks.